# Отличия передачи указателя на функцию в функцию

Tags: c++

В чем разница двух этих конструкций.

```
void Function(int operation(int) ) {}
void Function(int (*operation)(int) ) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае параметр имеет тип функции, во втором случае - указатель на функцию. Согласно пункту `11.3.5/5` стандарта C++, если параметр имеет тип функции `T`, то он преобразуется в тип указатель на функцию `T`.

> (N4659)
>   11.3.5 Functions
>
> 5. ...
>      After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”
>      ...

Согласно этому пункту в функции

```
void Function(int operation(int)) {}
```

параметр `operation` будет иметь тип `int (*)(int)`, т.е. такое объявление будет эквивалентно

```
void Function(int (*operation)(int) ) {}
```

Тоже самое происходит и с массивами.

Answer (score 3):

Абсолютно никакой разницы. Оба варианта означают передачу `int (*operation)(int)`.